# How to check if PyCharm Cython speedups are installed?

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm

PyCharm usually gives a notification when debugging saying "Python Debugger Extension Available".

I'm not sure I have them installed or not.  How can I check if they are?

I'm on:

- PyCharm 2023.1
- Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Hmm, seems Cython speedups are disabled at least on some platform / OS combinations (see [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-51378/Warning-message-when-debugging-3.10-on-Windows))

Answer (score 2):

This popup suggests installing debugger extensions, meaning PyCharm doesn't find any. Hence you have none.

One way to double-check if the debugger is using them or not is to add the `PYCHARM_DEBUG=True` environment variable to some Python run configuration (Run -> Edit Configurations)

[image]

Then run the configuration under the debugger and check for `Using Cython speedups` in the Debug toolwindow output.